# В чем отличие сокета (Socket) и конечной точки (EndPoint)?

Tags: сокет, сеть

Изучаю сетевое программирование, но никак не возьму в толк, в чем же принципиальное отличие сокета и конечной точки. Подробностей нигде нет.

Почему есть непонимание, а потому что, если коротко, то везде пишут так: "Сокет - один конец двухстороннего канала передачи данных, идентифицируется IP и портом". Ок, IP идентифицирует сетевой узел, порт идентифицирует процесс. Но при всем при этом есть некая конечная точка, которая тоже представляет собой IP и порт, то есть это тоже некая сущность отвечающая за адресацию в сети. Кажется, что это одно и то же. В чем теоретическое отличие?

Comment: "Сокет" - "физическая" сущность, объект в ОС, "конечная точка" - абстрактное логическое понятие.

Comment: Сокет, это если можно так выразиться, "здесь и сейчас" :) . Это сущность, которую Вы ассоциировали с чем-то (может быть с IP и портом, может быть с файлом). В unix/linux - это по сути и есть файл, в который пишутся и из которого читаются данные. Конечная точка - это то, что находится где-то там далеко (вероятно тоже сокет, но теоретически это неизвестно). Поэтому где-то там - это конечная точка (что-то, что подключается к Вам или к чему подключаетесь Вы). Да, может быть и локальная конечная точка, о которой все известно. И да. Необязательно сокет идентифицируется IP и портом.

Comment: @MaxZS попробую вас понять :) итак, вы считаете, что сокет - это канал, а конечная точка - то, к чему открыт канал. А это может быть любой ресурс: файл, поток, иные данные. Верно я вас понял? Чем ещё может быть идентифицирован сокет?

Comment: @Yes Man, не совсем... Канал - это, скорее, непосредственно само соединение. А сокет - это и есть сама точка, но идентифицированная и известная вам из чего она "состоит". В целом, это одно и тоже. Но... если образно... Петя передал сообщение своим коллегам. Вы знаете Петю, знаете как он может приврать или вообще не передать сообщения. Вы знаете, что Петя картавит и что он мужского поля. Но, при этом Вы понятия не имеете  кому он передал сообщение... Может мужчине и/или женщине, а может вообще он работает на границе и коллега у него собака, поверят ли ему, всегда ли ответят и выполнят просьбу.

Comment: @Yes Man, А может еще при этом его сообщение запишут на бумажку, а может наберут на компьютере. Вот Петя - человек (пусть человек и будет, типа, сокетом). Вы его знаете и можете его пощупать (пожать ему руку, набить лицо), а с конечной точкой ничего не сделаете и не знаете ничего о ней. Может Петя пришел на работу и коллегам сообщение в скайп набрал. Т.е. с другой стороны может быть и собака и компьютер. Вам ничего о ней не известно (конечная точка).

Comment: @Yes Man, Если Петя передаст по Вашей просьбе сообщение конкретной Маше, которую Вы знаете. Маша - человек, женского поля, она отреагирует на Ваше сообщение. Она тоже конечная точка (но, так как известной вам формы и содержания, а также поведения, является одновременно и сокетом). Кстати, Петя может сидеть в одной с Вами комнате, и также шепнуть Маше на ушко Ваше сообщение (т.е. они находятся на одном компе). И да... В описанном выше, опускаем того, кто это инициировал, т.е. непосредственно Вас. Не Вы являетесь начальным/конечным пунктами передачи сообщения, а Петя и кто-то/что-то где-то там.

Comment: @MaxZS Очень сумбурно :) Попробую опять вас понять и предложить другую аналогию: мы захотели передать служебную записку в IT отдел, но имя начальника мы не знаем, мы отдаем записку секретарю IT отдела - он и будет сокетом (узел получил наше сообщение), секретарь уже решил, что наверное надо передать записку начальнику, начальник и будет конечной точкой. Иными словами, конечная точка еще более конкретизирует адресата, но при этом может и совпадать с адресом сокета.

Comment: @Yes Man, Нет. Вы понятия не имеете как выглядит и из чего состоит конечная точка. Поэтому она так и называется, а не сокетом. Конечная точка может быть сокетом, но вовсе не обязательно. А в данном случае, Вы знаете конечного адресата и его сущность (то, что Вы не знаете как его зовут /его дескриптор в контексте сети/ ничего не значит). Да. Начальник будет конечной точкой. Но в тоже время он и сокет. Он такой же человек.

Comment: @Yes Man, В самом начале kff написал, что конечная точка - это абстрактное логическое понятие. О его свойствах по сути Вы не знаете ничего. Вы написали сервер, который принимает какую-то последовательность байт на сокет. Откуда эти байты придут? Вы знаете? Вы думаете, что только с другого такого же компа, который создал сокет и подключился к Вашему? А может там (в качестве бреда) провод оборвался и он коротит таким образом, что послал Вам какую-то последовательность байт? Какой же там тогда сокет? Это непонятно что. Это конечная точка.

Comment: @Yes Man, А может (в порядке бреда) роутер глюканул и развернул Вам взад Ваше же сообщение? Откуда же там сокет? Почему в порядке бреда? Да потому что это маловероятно, но, возможно, даст больше ясности о том, что нельзя предполагать что находится на другом конце. А в случае с начальником Вы знаете откуда Вам прилетит :)